# Template Syntax event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

Working on some experiments with javascript, let's say I have a function that returns some template syntax HTML in JavaScript.

```
function click() {
    alert("works")
}

function button() {
    return `
    <button onclick="click">Alert Me!</button>
    `;
}
```

the "onclick" attribute does not call the click function, which is just a function that pops up an alert.
Is there a way to add an event listener inside the "button()" function, without declaring any other code outside it?

Comment: Where is `click` defined…?

Comment: @deceze "click" is defined above my button function, it just alerts a string.

Comment: onclick="click()" ?

Comment: when you write: "the "onclick" attribute does not call the click function" do you mean that it is a problem or do you mean that this is ok?

Comment: as `<button onclick="click()">Alert Me!</button>` will not work, when you trying to return it, due to this element is not **DOM Ready** element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that my "click()" function was using a reserved signature.
Thank you for all the help

Comment: You are welcome. Still not clear what it is a solution to.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<button onclick='click'>Alert Me!</button>")
```

or
{locationToWrite}.innerHTML += "Alert Me!";
f.e.:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<button onclick='click'>Alert Me!</button>";
```